# Is there anything that I have to consider if I am adding to the prototype chain of React.Component

Tags: reactjs

I want to have some functions by default in all my components that I am creating. So the best way to do this is to add to the prototype chain of the React.Component.

If I were to add a default implementation to the life cycle hook of the component, will something misbehave??

Example:

```
let defaults = {
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log("I'm added to all components")
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps) {
        return !deepEqual(nextProps, this.props);
    }
};

React.Component.prototype = Object.assign(React.Component.prototype, defaults);
```